# Load a Pandas Dataframe from excel in SharePoint

Tags: python, pandas, api, sharepoint, office365

I want to load a DataFrame from wmy colleague's sharepoint. My colleague already give me an edit access. I think i dont have problem with my excel file because i can load the excel after i downloaded the excel file on my local machine.

I have used this code :

```
#import all the libraries
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File 
import io
import pandas as pd

#target url taken from sharepoint and credentials
url = 'this is the url of my excel'
username = 'myname@mydomainemail.co.id'
password = 'mypassword'
sheetname = 'mytabsheetname'

#Authentication
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
    ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
    web = ctx.web
    ctx.load(web)
    ctx.execute_query()
    print('Authentication sucessfull')

else:
    print(ctx_auth.get_last_error())
    
response = File.open_binary(ctx, url)

#save data to BytesIO stream
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0) #set file object to start

df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheet_name = sheetname , engine = 'openpyxl')
```

But i got an error "BadZipFile: File is not a zip file".
I've also tried to change the engine to 'xlrd' but i got an error

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\r\n<!DOCT'
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue,
create a .env file and create 4 variables (sharepoint_email, sharepoint_password, sharepoint_url_site, sharepoint_site_name).

can you try this code?

```
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File 
import environ

env = environ.Env()
env.read_env('.env')
USERNAME = env('sharepoint_email')
PASSWORD = env('sharepoint_password')
SHAREPOINT_SITE = env('sharepoint_url_site') # https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/SharepointSiteName
SHAREPOINT_SITE_NAME = env('sharepoint_site_name') # SharepointSiteName
SHAREPOINT_DOC = env('sharepoint_doc_library') # Shared Documents/MyFolder

class SharepointApi:
    def _auth(self):
        conn = ClientContext(SHAREPOINT_SITE).with_credentials(
            UserCredential(
            USERNAME,
            PASSWORD
            )
        )
        print("Connected to Sharepoint Site")
        return conn
    
    def _get_file(self, file_path):
        conn = self._auth()
        file_url = f"/sites/{SHAREPOINT_SITE_NAME}/{SHAREPOINT_DOC}/{file_path}"
        file = File.open_binary(conn, file_url)
        return file.content
    
def get_file(file_name, folder_name):
    file_obj = SharepointApi()._get_file(f'{folder_name}/{file_name}')
    return BytesIO(file_obj)

# if __name__ == "__main__":
args = {
    'folder_name': 'Folder_Name',
    'file_name': 'XXX.xlsx'
}
file = get_file(args['file_name'], args['folder_name'])
data = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None)
data.head(2)
```